# Proof of membership on a merkle tree

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, cryptocurrency, hash-tree

I read the zcash paper recently. But I have been puzzled by a question. How did the authors prove that the coin commitment appears as a leaf of a Merkle tree with root rt? Apparently, the authors provided authentication paths for a commitment. But how to provide them in a private way?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, an in depth answer for me would be too long and is actually the scope of the Zerocash paper itself, which I recommend you re-read thoroughly.

**A high-level answer:** Instead of providing the authentication path, which would leak the position of the coin commitment in the tree and break anonymity, Zerocash gives a *zero-knowledge proof of knowledge (ZKPoK)* of such a valid authentication path. (In fact, the ZKPoK argues much more than just the validity of the path.)

The ZKPoK is instantiated so that it is *succinct* and *efficient-to-verify* via the techniques and implementation of **[BCTV13]**, which is in turn based on the Pinocchio zk-SNARK from **[PGHR13e]**.

### References

[BCTV13] Succinct Non-Interactive Zero Knowledge for a von Neumann Architecture; by Eli Ben-Sasson and Alessandro Chiesa and Eran Tromer and Madars Virza; in Cryptology ePrint Archive, Report 2013/879; 2013; https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/879

[PGHR13e] Pinocchio: Nearly Practical Verifiable Computation; by Bryan Parno and Craig Gentry and Jon Howell and Mariana Raykova; in Cryptology ePrint Archive, Paper 2013/279; 2013; https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/279